# LiteIDE no autocomplete

Tags: ide, go, liteide

I'm trying to use LiteIDE (the Go IDE) on Linux 32-bit. Everything works except for autocomplete. Builds, running, everything works. The `gocode` binary seems to be running tho:

```
ithisa@miyasa ~> ps aux | grep gocode
ithisa   10003  0.0  0.0 823788  2624 pts/1    Sl+  09:06   0:00 /home/ithisa/scratch/liteide/bin/gocode -s -sock unix -addr localhost:37373
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Auto-complete works for me, using 12.04 LTS (32 bit). I followed EXACTLY the instructions here, **all of them**: [FreeBSD, Linux, Mac OS X and NetBSD tarballs](http://golang.org/doc/install#bsd_linux) Then I installed LiteIDE from here: [LiteIDE x18.2.1 Linux (x86 32bit)](http://code.google.com/p/golangide/downloads/detail?name=liteidex18.2.1.linux-386.tar.bz2) Everything worked first time, every time.

Comment: Hmm. I was using the Debian Unstable-supplied Go from the repos rather than manually installing from Google...Debian usually packages things correctly; probably the reason is that it was Debian Unstable, which sometimes has not-so-tested packages.

Comment: I installed the official Go packages. Still no autocompletion...

Comment: DK - I would remove everything and start from scratch. I had nothing at all related to Go on my machine when I started, and followed the instructions exactly. I was amazed at how hassle free it was - I had a project (with autocomplete) running in LiteIDE in about half an hour from start @ 0. I'm finding I like LiteIDE - I come from Delphi/C++/Python and I always need a good IDE - hate messing with all the other bs - just want to write my code and build it. LiteIDE seems to handle the job-good debugging, tracing-at least enough to get you going. Have not done any big projects with Go yet.

Comment: I just did remove everything and start from scratch. All the go tools work, everything in LiteIDE works, EXCEPT for autocomplete on the existing libraries (autocomplete on keywords, and stuff I write on my own, work). Seems to be a problem with `gocode`.

Comment: OK, well - I can't say for sure that autoComplete works right for **everything**. Haven't paid that much attention yet. Maybe I've only been seeing it on the things you mentioned now. I will be messing around with it some more over the next few days....

Comment: OK - I was messing with it over the weekend - looks like I've got the same behavior over here: No autoComplete for imported packages, just for keywords and locally defined code. Have not tried with my own packages yet.

Comment: I had a problem like this that went away after I set set some default paths, though I don't know which part of the setup process fixed it. 1) In LiteIDE, try View->Manage GOPATH and put your workspace dir and your Go directory under 'Custom directories': `/home/bob/gowork` and `/home/bob/go`, say. 2) Use the "Edit environment" button in the Environment toolbar (also accessible through View->Options->LiteEnv) to make sure `GOROOT=/home/bob/go` and `GOPATH=/home/bob/gowork` are set for the environment you're using. 3) `killall gocode` and restart LiteIDE. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to set a GOROOT=. To set it within LiteIDE, look for the environment toolbar; it should be a a dropdown, probably with "system" preselected, and a button. Click the button to bring up the Edit Environment pane, then double-click "system.env", or whichever environment was picked in the dropdown.

Change the line that starts `GOROOT=` to point to your 'go' directory. Plain old $HOME/go is a common setting if you installed it from golang.org, and if you don't know where it is, running `go env` will show the `GOROOT` that the Go toolchain itself is using. And of course if the line is commented out (`#GOROOT=`...) remove the `#`. Save.

If the toolbar is missing entirely, View -> Environment toolbar unhides it.

It's probably also worth setting GOROOT and related settings in your `.bashrc`, so tools started from the command line see it. I installed Go and LiteIDE in my homedir and my workspace is `~/gocode`, so mine is like:

```
export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$HOME/liteide/bin:$PATH"
export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/gocode
```

I can't be certain this is actually your issue, but if I unset my GOROOT the symptom matches what you're seeing: completion works on my code, but not on the standard library. Good luck!

Comment: What should I set GOROOT to? Debian installs Go into `/usr/lib` and `/usr/bin` and a whole bunch of other Unixy places; should I uninstall Debian's Go and install Go into my homedir?

Comment: Um, good question. Running `go env` will give you Go's environment variables, and it looks like your `GOROOT` will be `/usr/lib/go`. (Updating my answer.)

Comment: As a windows user I changed system to win64 in the dropdown and gocode started working immediately. Yay code prediction/auto complete

Answer (score 2):

Did you install gocode?

https://github.com/nsf/gocode

Also, does nothing autocomplete or just new packages? Packages need to be installed to autocomplete. Do you have a standard install setup?

Your GOROOT and GOPATH should also be correctly setup.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the exact same problem, except for 64-bit linux (ArchLinux)

I got this solved by:

set up correct `GOROOT` and `GOPATH`, for example:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep GO
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
export GOPATH=~/goroot
PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
bash
```

installing/starting gocode daemon

```
$ go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
$ gocode -addr=:37373
$ gocode status
```

set correct GOROOT on LiteIDE config file:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/liteide/liteenv/linux64.env
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
```

Comment: The GOROOT=/usr/lib/go in your last line was what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me gocode (autocomplete) broke in LiteIDE after updating Go to the latest version.

What I did was make sure GOPATH was set correct. Then install gocode:

```
go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
```

Then remove the gocode version from the `liteide/bin/` folder, because else LiteIDE will use its own version (I only renamed it just in case).

Now when you boot LiteIDE it should say

```
GolangCode: Found gocode at <YOUR GOPATH>/bin/gocode
```

instead of LiteIDE using its own version.