# liteide go code completion for google cloud libraries

Tags: go, liteide

Im writing some go code in litede all the library's    are "working" fine
except the google cloud library's.
I cant figure out a way how to get liteide auto complete the google cloud library's  .

the sdk is installed well i can build and deploy the code.

thanks,

miki

Comment: While not strictly off-topic, for greater chances to have this question replied, it should be asked on the Liteide forum instead: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liteide-dev

Comment: There was another (also bountied!) related question; the short answer was to make sure GOROOT and GOPATH are set in the environment setup LiteIDE uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876902/liteide-no-autocomplete . The one difference here is that if the SDK is installed somewhere different from your main GOPATH, you need to find it and add it.

Comment: @twotwotwo 
The SDK is here  /home/mik/go_appengine/
and the GOPATH is here  /home/mik/go-programs
if i understand you correct the SDK need to be in here /home/mik/go-programs ??

Comment: No--change the GOPATH to include the SDK, like `GOPATH=/home/mik/go-programs:/home/mik/go_appengine`. It might be `go_appengine` still isn't the right directory; look for a `src/` dir with directories under it with Go package names, and add the parent of that to the end of `GOPATH` (using `:` as the separator).

Comment: @twotwotwo All the Go packages  are under  /home/mik/go_appengine/groot 
so i added it to the GOPATH and now the it look like that 
/home/mik/go-programs:/home/mik/go_appengine/goroot/
i restart the machine and the result is the same....

Comment: @MIkCode Gotcha--unfortunately I can't think of what else to try then.

Answer (score 1):

At the end it was a metter of finding the right path  and adding its to the $GOPATH it only took my 4 days :)

This is the correct path that  enabling  me to get app engine SDK  autocomplation  with LiteIDE

```
SDK_FOLDER/goroot/pkg/
```